# Setting and clearing an "is-idle" variable when going in and out of idle mode?

Tags: idle-timer

I understand in general about idle timers in emacs, but I'm having trouble figuring out how to do the following ...

I want to set an `is-idle` variable to `t` when emacs is in an idle state, and I want that variable to set to `nil` when emacs is not idle.

Why do I want this? It's because I have written signal handlers for sigusr1 and sigusr2 which get invoked when my emacs process receives either of these external signals. I want the handlers not to run if emacs doesn't happen to be idle at the moment that the sigusr1 or sigusr2 signals are received.

In other words, I want my signal handler to look like this:

```
(when is-idle
   ;; do all the sigusr1/sigusr2 processing
   ;; ... etc. ...
   )
```

I haven't figured out how to manage this with an idle timer, nor with any other emacs facilities.

Instead of a variable, `is-idle` could be a function. I don't really care which it is. I just want to know at the moment that the signal is received as to whether my emacs session is idle or not.

Thanks in advance.

**Update ...**

I came across the `(current-idle-time)` function. Here's its doc string ...

```
Return the current length of Emacs idleness, or nil.
The value when Emacs is idle is a list of four integers (HIGH LOW USEC PSEC)
in the same style as (current-time).

The value when Emacs is not idle is nil.

PSEC is a multiple of the system clock resolution.
```

I'm going to do some investigation as to whether this function will provide what I'm looking for, and I'll report back.

Comment: I presume you've attempted to make your signal handlers schedule their work with an idle timer, and that hasn't worked for some reason? If I've read the question correctly, that *sounds* like what you want to do, so show us the code you tried to use for that...

Comment: Thank you. I already understand how to do that. However, I actually want the opposite to take place. I want the signal handler to do its work either (1) ***exactly*** at the moment that the signal is delivered, or (2) not at all, if emacs is not idle. I don't know if this is even possible under emacs.

Comment: The `current-idle-time` function might do what I want. See the update I added to my original message.

Comment: i.e. the answer I posted 3 hours ago? :)

Comment: Sorry, I didn't do a "refresh" of my web page before posting my own answer, so I didn't see yours.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even though `(current-idle-time)` only seems to return a meaningful value within the context of an idle handler, I figured out how to use it for my purpose ...

```
;; Initialize to idle mode upon emacs startup.
(defvar my-last-idle t
  "*Last idle time value.")

(defun my-pre-command-hook ()
  (setq my-last-idle nil))

(defun my-idle-timer-hook ()
  (setq my-last-idle (current-idle-time)))

(add-hook 'pre-command-hook 'my-pre-command-hook)
(run-with-idle-timer 1 t 'my-idle-timer-hook)
```

Then, my sigusr1/sigusr2 handler can do this ...

```
(when my-last-idle
  ;; Do my signal-handling stuff.
  ;; ... etc. ...
  )
```

Answer (score 0):

<kbd>C-h</kbd><kbd>f</kbd> `current-idle-time`

```
current-idle-time is a built-in function in ‘C source code’.

(current-idle-time)

Return the current length of Emacs idleness, or nil.
The value when Emacs is idle is a list of four integers (HIGH LOW USEC PSEC)
in the same style as (current-time).

The value when Emacs is not idle is nil.

PSEC is a multiple of the system clock resolution.
```

Comment: Yes, this is the function I was looking for ... sort of. However, it seems to return `nil`, even when emacs has been idle for a very long time. I believe that it only returns a meaningful value within the context of an idle handler. I'm investigating further.

Comment: I can run a normal timer which displays expected idle-time results. Assuming you're testing with your signal handler, maybe signal handling makes Emacs non-idle. (If that's not how you're testing, what *are* you doing? Obviously user interaction of any kind makes Emacs non-idle, so you'll always get `nil` if you invoke the function directly).

Comment: Yes, if I have a timer displaying increasing idleness, and I send `SIGUSR1`, Emacs ceases to be idle.

Comment: That behavior makes sense. My answer (below) takes this into account, and it solves my problem.